# WPF design rendering is dramaticaly slow Visual Studio 2008? Are there any tweaks that could speed it up?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml

I just wanted to do some tutorials in WPF but I find that the designer works very slow in comparision to Windows Forms/GDI+.

Are there any tweaks to speed it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just after a bit of XAML editing, you can use a separate editor, such as XamlPad.  That has much quicker rendering than the VS designer.

Answer (score 3):

I turned it off.

1. Right click the xaml file in Solution explorer,
2. use Source code (Text) Editor
3. Set it as default

Good thing is Intellisense still works!
In case you need to view the Design view occasionally, you can still Right click ->  Design view.

Answer (score 2):

Turn it off. The VS XAML designer is awful and doesn't work anyway as soon as your XAML is non-trivial. Go into your [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7w5e5s.aspx) and map the .xaml extension to the regular XML Editor.

Answer (score 0):

you can look in the following link.
quite same as the previous answers.["How to speed up Visual Studio 2008's slow WPF designer"](http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid8_gci1356218_mem1,00.html)

Comment: The link is behind a (pay) wall, either extend your answer to include information or remove your answer.